# Load joomla framework in subdomain folder

Tags: php, joomla

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$mosConfig_absolute_path = dirname( __FILE__ );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'methods.php');
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'configuration.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'base'.DS.'object.php');
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'database'.DS.'database.php');
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'database'.DS.'database'.DS.'mysql.php');
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'filesystem'.DS.'folder.php');
```

It worked when the .php file was in the root folder, but when I call it from subdomain I had an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load the php <my php file>. Origin <subdomain> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Frankly speaking it works(sends me an e-mail), but callback doesn't...

So I moved the php file to subdomain directory. Now I have 500 error. Need help. Thank you!

Comment: What your version? 1.5 2.5 3.0?

Comment: Did you try? `<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>`

Comment: Yeah, it works! But I'm in doubt about safety of this line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All Domains:**

```
<?php 
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
?>
```

**Allowed Domains:**

```
<?php 
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.com, http://domain2.com'); 
?>
```